# Renaming fields of struct imported from dll

Tags: c++, c, dll

I'm building a framework for a series of compiled Simulink models (they are code generated into C DLLs). In each of the dlls there are entry points that you can use to access the input and output of the simulations, and they can for instance look like this (from the dll´s header file):

```
typedef struct {
  Ms_MainBus Ms_MainBus_a;
} ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical;
```

However, eventhough all of the models have the same I/O data structure (Ms_MainBus), the actual variable names change, so for instance in another dll the signal might be called `Ms_MainBus_b` instead of `Ms_MainBus_a`. This is extremely annoying, as I try to build a generic framework that can handle a large number of these models, and shouldn't require knowledge of what letter Matlab has appended to the signal name.

To solve this, I tried the following:

Defined a struct that has the signal name I want every model to use

```
typedef struct {
   Ms_MainBus MainBus;
} stdInput;
```

I then proceed to import the input and output variables from the dll into a class called Ele.

In Ele.h, I first try to override the input structure from the header file

```
#undef ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical
#define ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical stdOutput
```

And then declare the input variable

```
ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical (*output);
```

And in Ele.cpp

```
this->output = (ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical*)GetProcAddress(this->lib, "vcts_electrical_Y");
```

It works, and I can access `output.MainBus`, but if I try to change the value of the input to the model, nothing happens. It's like the dll uses another workspace than my code. I haven't had that problem before I started with this renaming business, so I'm guessing the problem is in the `#undef, #define` part, correct?

How should I do?

Comment: The declaration of `output` is as a pointer to `ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical`, not a pointer to a function returning `ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical`.

Comment: first `ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical` is a type not a `#define` I doubt that preprocessor will replace it with the library's `ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical`.

second `ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical (*output);` this essentially means a pointer to your structure instance. so, `this->output = (ExternalOutputs_vcts_electrical*)GetProcAddress(this->lib, "vcts_electrical_Y");` this is totally wrong (you are taking func ptr into instance ptr), unless you typecast it to proper calling-convension with appropriate parameter.

Can you post the function signature of "vcts_electrical_Y" this function?

Comment: If you don't like a .h file then just edit it.  Be prepared to have to do it more than once if the DLL owner changes it.  So you might not want to leave him in the dark about your changes.

Comment: If the data types are identical and the labels are the only things changing, you could just cast to a pre-determined struct type.

Comment: Yes Dogbert, you're absolutely right. :) Can't believe I didn't realize that before, but I was confused by the (imo very weird) architecture of the header/dll you get from the code generation. I built getters/setters that cast to a common type now, and it works brilliantly. Thanks!

Can't vote up your comment, otherwise I would've.